# Can we hide the tail end of overly long answers?

Tags: feature-request, answers

### The Problem

Many questions have answers which are of high quality, but which are also extremely long (compared to how short they *could* be).
Some examples (see the accepted answer):

- [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/5740428)
- [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/5740428)
- [How does guaranteed copy elision work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38043319/5740428)
- [Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/5740428)

While there's nothing wrong with writing a long and elaborate answer, many readers may be interested in a concise summary of the topic, rather than a 20 paragraph blog post about every little detail.
Overly long answers create two major problems:

1. For readers who want to browse answers to get an overview, long answers towards the top force them to scroll through the entire top answer first, and this can be a huge scroll distance. **The result is bad UX.**
2. The longer an answer towards the top is, the fewer people are exposed to the answers below. **The result is a more uneven and unfair distribution of upvotes, and lengthening your answer can be used as a malicious tactic to prevent your competition from gaining upvotes!**

### Could this be solved through sorting modes?

First of all, no. No matter how you sort, the top answer could always be overly long. This only mitigates the issue; it doesn't solve it.

Secondly, sorting modes are somewhat broken at the moment. For example, on the question [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/5740428), at the time of writing, all four sorting modes show the same answer at the top, because it is simulatenously

- the most upvoted answer
- the trending answer
- the most recently updated answer
- the oldest answer

### Proposed Solution

I believe the best way to address this issue is through UI.
Add a cut-off point beyond which you have to click to reveal the rest, such as:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat ...
>
> ---
>
> <kbd>Click to reveal more</kbd>

It would probably be best to base the cut-off point on the size of the rendered Markdown content.

**Clarification: The cut-off point shouldn't be anywhere near as close as in this lorem ipsum example!** The point is that if you make your answer a novel, not every reader is forced to scroll past that novel. In the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279550/5740428, the cut-off point should be somewhere around the second major heading `An in-depth explanation`.

Concise answers (up to a few paragraphs?) would be unaffected, but answers which are practically novels would be limited. If a user was interested in an overly long answer, they could click to see the full content; otherwise, they could scroll past more easily.

**To clarify, I am not suggesting to lower the hard length limit.**

Comment: I miss the app. It had up/down arrows to jump between answers.

Comment: What would a good length cutoff be? Based on screen size? Based on line count? Based on the [gap a bridge of ants can cover](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HViRoND11mo)?

Comment: @Cerbrus I believe it should be based on the size of the rendered Markdown content. I'm not sure if screen size should play any role in it. Lines don't translate into rendered size directly.

Comment: @Laurel I'm aware it's not a perfect replacement but keyboard shortcuts can do that on desktop. If you enable them, **J** will go down the post list, **K** will go up. Doesn't work on mobile, of course, and it's not super intuitive to just pick up, either.

Comment: I'm kind of against this - I feel the site already tends to attract way too short answers (Most answers I see in reviews that are actually longer than a couple paragraphs are old audits), and I feel like hiding parts of well researched answers punishes them in a way. I could however get behind up/down functionality on mobile similar to the existing keyboard shortcuts if it could be non-intrusive and not terrible (please don't give us Discourse scroll bars)

Comment: Somewhat related: [Add functionality to collapse long text/code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348073/2821954)

Comment: I'm still unsure. On one hand, this can be helpful. On the other hand, hiding parts forces users to change their writing style into more like a marketing blurb, i.e. eye-catching in the beginning so that readers are interested to see more, but then disappointed with the quality of the rest (or heck, hidden long AI-generated content/spam!?).

Comment: @LW001 you're not punishing people for providing a long answer if you make a cut-off point after 5 paragraphs or so. You're only making it so that if you decide to turn your answer into a novel, you don't take away everyone else's space. Obviously, the outcome depends on where you draw the line.

Comment: @AndrewT. I think you got the wrong impression from the example. I'm not proposing to put the cut-off point after one paragraph or so. Probably somewhere between 5-10 paragraphs so that the majority of existing SO answers comfortably fit inside the limit.

Comment: Oof, yea, the possibility to hide spam in a collapsed block has put me off of this suggestion... That's awful.

Comment: @JanSchultke I don't think paragraph counts are a good factor because some may have a habit of writing very long paragraphs and others may have a habit of writing each sentence as a new paragraph (I have seen both extremes. Should the community edits to improve them? Probably yes, but then they may also inadvertently change the intent of post visibility). Meanwhile, Stack Exchange already sets a hard limit of 30000 characters per post, so I guess it's better to use characters for the limit, if implemented.

Comment: @Cerbrus if someone puts spam into their answer ... just flag it? I don't really understand what danger this poses. And if someone does put spam into their answer, they would be subject to moderation. What exactly does this enable someone to do?

Comment: @AndrewT. I am not sure if you have read my post. It states that the limit should be based on the size of the rendered Markdown content, not based on paragraphs. The "5 paragraphs" is just a vague estimate of how much visual content we are talking about. The hard character limit is massive, as can be seen in the massive size of the answers that some people have provided. (See the examples I have linked to).

Comment: I think this is a great suggestion as I personally find long answers to trail off the problem at hand more often than not. Yes, they provide background knowledge and have you understand the underlying issues, but they can very easily become pointlessly long and tedious to read.

Comment: A big advantage of having all answers in full length by default is that one can simply use the browser search for a function name etc.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I think there technically could be a way to use builtin browser functionality to search in text that isn't visible at the time, but yeah, that's a good point. The solution might be ugly if it does work. To be fair, I don't find myself searching for text on answers too often, and this only affects overly long answers that are practically novels. In most cases, things would work the same.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz That could be at least partially mitigated by providing an expand all button.

Comment: @JanSchultke the problem is that the spam is "hidden" and requires users to actively look for it, making it much less likely to be flagged & deleted.

Comment: @Cerbrus if no one ever looks at the spam, and no one cares about it ... then what's the problem? If a tree falls in the woods, and no one hears it ... does it happen? I still don't understand what issue you see with people posting spam in places that no one ever sees and cares about. And realistically, the odds of hiding something on SO are *very slim*. This website has tons of users, and at least the person who posted the question is likely to read answers.

Comment: _"In places that no one ever sees and cares about."_ I don't think that applies to long answers. Are you suggesting to hide the tail end of long answers to save space, or because you're of the opinion that no one ever cares about them? You can't have both.

Comment: Also, if this feature causes no one to ever look at that spam, I think that's a very good reason __not__ to implement the feature. We don't need to add features to make it easier to spam the site.

Comment: @Cerbrus ***no, you can't have both.*** You can't simultaneously make the claim that spam hidden in long answers is a problem because users don't see it frequently, and also make the claim that it's doing damage to the website. If users don't see it, it's not doing damage. If users are seeing it, then users will flag it. Either I'm missing something obvious, or your argument is based on cognitive dissonance.

Comment: Mate, you made a suggestion for a new feature. Then you're saying it's not a problem that it's going to allow more spam to survive because no one will expand long answers, anyway... Then what's the point of your suggested feature?

Comment: "you have to click to reveal the rest" -- as opposed to just rolling the scroll wheel with a single finger, and just reading on, I have to hunt down some button? Not sure how that's better -- at least for someone with non-zero attention span, who has no problem reading things.

Comment: @DanMašek obviously it's easier to read a specific post if it's fully expanded from the start. However, it becomes more difficult to browse other posts. I believe there can be sane middle ground such as hiding a portion of excessively long answers. It's all about which point you choose specifically. I agree that if you make the cut-off point too short, this leads to bad UX, and that should be avoided.

Comment: [Quora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora) (and other sites) uses it, so it is probably (unfortunately) coming here sooner or later (it is already comments and lately in *"Related questions"* for questions without answers. [Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77038892/to-what-extent-can-i-treat-classes-and-types-as-objects-themselves-and-why-does).). Our only defense is the usual inertia. ***It requires mouse clicks (or the equivalent) to use. Very bad.***

Comment: I absolutely hate websites that hide content behind “click for more” functionality. Like so much hatred I actively avoid them

Comment: I can see some merit in this for questions which have many answers. Usually you can tell from the first paragraphs if an answer is going to be relevant to you or not, having long answers collapsed specifically in the case of there being many answers (say: when the site splits up the answers into pages?) can help to skim and can even help to put late undervalued answers (where I tend to find quite some of my solutions...) more in the spotlight. But as a general "answer is long" rule, no. That'll hinder more than it helps.

Comment: @Gimby What if answer has some special section with huge warning. You will not miss that even if you scroll, but you can easily miss it with collapsed answer. and warnings commonly come after full explanation and are not the first thing on top unless it is directly related to the question itself.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar the floor is not lava, in the very, very specific case I detail when you do spot an answer among the mountain of answers which might look like a winner, I assume you will click to expand it and not break a finger or sustain bodily harm in any other way in the process.

Comment: @Gimby If I am looking for solution, then I will read all answers fully. Or at least will quickly browse though them all to see whether there is some hidden gem or piece of information worth knowing. And if we start from the position that this is the issue only when there is plenty of other answers, then I suppose scrolling won't kill you either.

Answer (score 16):

No.

> many readers may be interested in a concise summary of the topic

Hiding answer content is not creating a concise summary of anything, it's just adding an extra hoop ("click to expand") to jump through for people who want to read that entire answer.

> The result is a more uneven and unfair distribution of upvotes, and lengthening your answer can be used as a malicious tactic to prevent your competition from gaining upvotes!

It could equally be argued that such a feature will unfairly discriminate against users who make the effort to write long and comprehensive answers, because that extra hoop disincentivises people from clicking to read the entire answer. Or to put it another way, it will discincentivise users from writing long answers because they know that most people will never read them.

Stack Overflow is not TikTok. Programming is not tl;dr. Understanding is everything, and long answers provide that understanding. They are arguably the most valuable content on this site, and the potential of neutering them in any way shape or form leaves a poor taste in my mouth.

Buttons to move between answers, as noted by @Laurel in their comment on this question, would have the same desired effect but none of the drawbacks I've noted. I'd be happy for those to be added, but let's leave the presentation of answers as-is, please.

Comment: I think this answer fails to consider the suggested cut-off point. I have said that a very sizable chunk should be visible by default; the cut-off point should come after multiple paragraphs. This is not anywhere near "tl; dr" only; this is not anywhere near turning Stack Overflow into "TikTok". If you have taken the time to read my question in full, then I don't understand how you could have arrived at such a conclusion. Maybe it is my bad. If you haven't, then this answer is pointless and insulting.

Comment: I appreciate that there are keyboard shortcuts for navigating between answers. That is a useful feature. However, without evidence that a substantial portion of users uses them, or even knows about them, are they really a solution? Obscure features that a selected few know are not a solution to a systemic problem. I would call these shortcuts obscure, because I've used SO for half a decade and just now learned about them.

Comment: It doesn't matter how sizeable the chunk is or not; obscuring *any* part of an answer by default is a problem. The keyboard shortcuts should be augmented by buttons.

Comment: Yeah sure, it is a problem to some people. To some other people it is also a problem that massive questions take up a lot of space. Either way, there is some problem. A good answer would quantify these problems, explore trade-offs, and draw a reasonable conclusion. It doesn't help me if you just boldly say "No.", list a few unquantified problems, and then draw a conclusion with no real discussion or trade-offs made. I think the buttons would be a good idea though. It's not like navigation buttons fully solve the problem on their own though, I believe.

Comment: Look, Jan, I realize you're new to Meta... You might not realize that the burden of proof you're demanding equally applies to _your_ claims. If long text is such a large problem, prove it. Back it up with some data. Provide sources stating it's an issue. If you can't do that, you can't honestly dismiss answers opposing your opinion, for the same reasons.

Comment: @Cerbrus if it looks like I'm dismissive of this answer, it's because it looks to me like the author hasn't actually read the full question, not even the disclaimers that I have put in bold text. I also feel insulted by the implication that I want to turn Stack Overflow into "TikTok" or something. An answer should be able to provide more insight into a topic, instead of countering with a hastily written opinion piece that strawmans the author of the question. And quite frankly, I don't need be educated about Meta by someone who follows me on Meta in every comment section just to argue.

Comment: Jan, I'm very active on Meta. It's not weird that we run into each other. Accusing me of targeted interaction like that in counter-productive. You're dismissing this answer as a "hastily written opinion" and a "strawman" (as you've dismissed a lot of other answers), but this answer is based on years of experience on this site. You completely missed the point of my last comment. I'm asking you to __hold your own claims to the same standards that you demand from us__. Your suggestion here is based on your opinion. Back that up with data. ___Prove___ that it's a problem that needs fixing.

Comment: This: _"it looks to me like the author hasn't actually read the full question"_ is a ___major___ red flag, by the way. You're just dismissing Ian's answer, using an approach often used by users with less-than-benign intentions.

Comment: @Cerbrus please, just leave me alone. I really don't believe that you want to do anything but argue, and be right.

Comment: Jan, you're posting suggestions on a public website. Other users are free to (dis)agree, and write about that. You're being very dismissive of any disagreement, and I'm asking you to hold yourself to the same standard as you're expecting from others. I don't want to "be right", if I'm wrong I want to be __proven__ wrong, not just dismissed as _"that's just your opinion"_.

Comment: @Cerbrus I have had productive discussions with many people here. All I'm asking is that *you* stop following me around in every comment section just to reprimand, attack, or misrepresent me. You've never even agreed with or acknowledged even a tiny fraction of any statement I've made over something like 50 comments. You're just arguing for the sake of it, with zero compromise.

Comment: My first comment here was just me asking for some extra details... Then I realized this could hide spam, and stated that I thought this was a bad idea... Then ___you___ started dismissing my concern with _"if they're not gonna see spam, what's the problem"_, which is a ___horrible___ justification to implement a new feature... But you're just dismissing it. Here's a solution: If you don't like my feedback on your feature request, you can just ignore it. You don't get to tell me where I can and can not provide feedback.

Comment: @Cerbrus it wasn't dismissal. I was genuinely asking for clarification because I didn't understand your concern, and was interested in your opinion. Your problem is that you interpret other people's statements in the most negative light possible all the time, so you end up misrepresenting them, arguing endlessly in circles, and this also makes you interpret a question for clarification as a "dismissal" of your opinion. I can't help you with that. It also means the argument goes on forever, because you can't have your arch enemies have the last word, right? ;)

Comment: @Cerbrus Your first comment here (the first comment to the question actually) was already making fun of the question... and throughout the discussion you kept making remarks to discredit the suggestion without acknowledging its benefits at all. Admitedly you aren't the only one doing that, but that doesn't mean its a good thing.

Comment: @Cuzy: That first comment was a serious question, with a lighthearted arbitrary measurement. If anything, I was making fun of my own question there... Then I realized hiding spam was a problem, and my further replies to that are just about that specific issue.

Comment: @Cuzy I was genuinely puzzled by the answer, because I have made it clear in bold text that the cut-off point should be quite substantial, i.e. 5-10 paragraphs. I genuinely believe that the snarky remark in the answer about "Stack Overflow is not TikTok" could only be the result of not having read my question in full, or deliberately misrepresenting it. Either it's an insulting misrepresentation, or the author hasn't read the relevant parts of my post. I won't retract any of that; to me it's unacceptable.

Comment: @JanSchultke how is comparing this site to TikTok, to highlight the contrasts and thus bolster my argument, snarky?

Comment: @IanKemp when you say *"Stack Overflow is not TikTok. Programming is not tl;dr."*, and my post obviously doesn't advocate for making Stack Overflow into anything in this style, then what point are you addressing? It's a blatant misrepresentation of what I've said and completely misses the point made in my post. My post has made it clear that I only intend to target excessively long answers spanning a vast distance, not crop all answers down to a few lines, Tik Tok style.

Comment: I think Ian's intention was to state _"Brevity is not an aspect we value here"_. Factual correctness, and a complete explanation is more valuable.

Comment: @Cerbrus It's not that we don't value brevity at all, it's simply that like Wikipedia, we value verbosity higher.

Comment: On the other hand... this feature may encourage answerers to do better about getting to the point earlier on in the answer rather than it taking skimming/reading over 2 pages of content before getting to what we're after.

Comment: @KevinB I absolutely don't want to discourage anyone who is a fan of verbosity from submitting an answer. Long answers can always be edited down to be more concise; short answers can't be edited up. Yes, it's possible to attempt to flesh the latter out - but that has a good chance of either going against the original author's intent, or just adding fluff for the sake of it.